# AngularJS Filtering Object with Array of IDs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have an array of objects populating a multi-select. I want to display the selected objects in my directive and am having difficulty as I'm a angular newb.

What I want to do

```
{{selectedReport.rooms | filter: {id: Vars[var.name]}  }}
```

Show selectedReport.rooms where room.id IN Var[var.name].  Var[var.name] is my ng-model binding. If I select 4 reports it may look like ["2","4","23","64"]

I need to access the selectedReport.rooms objects based upon those IDs. I'm not sure how to do this in the angular way.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

My directive code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('lodgicalWebApp')
  .directive('lodReportVariableRoomFilter', [ function ( Report, Rooms) {


    return {
      template: ' \
      <div class="form-group" ng-show="selectedReport.rooms.length > 0"> \
        <label for="{{var.name}}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{var.name}}</label> \
        <div class="col-sm-5"> \
          <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="Vars[var.name]"  class="form-control"> \
            <option ng-repeat="room in selectedReport.rooms track by room.id" value="{{room.id}}" >{{room.name}}</option> \
          </select> \
      </div> {{ selectedReport.rooms | filter: {id: Vars[var.name]} }}\
    </div> \
    <div class="form-group" ng-show="selectedReport.rooms.length == 0"> \
      <label class="col-sm-8 control-label">Loading Rooms...</label> \
    </div> \
  </div>',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attr){
        scope.Vars[scope.var.name] = [""] ;
      }
    };

  }]);



//example of selectedReport.rooms
selectedReport.rooms = [{id:'', name:'(all)'}, {id:'1', name:'102'}, {id:'3', name: '104c'}];
```

Vars[var.name] is just a Scope variable that holds all my directive input selections.

```
//example of Vars[var.name]
Vars[var.name] = ['1','3'];
```

What I want:
 Objects after filter:

```
Room [ id: '1', name: '102']
Room [ id: '3', name: '104c']
```

Final output

```
 102, 104c
```

Comment: You need to show more code than this. Are you using ng-options in a <select> If so, you don't want curly braces in the statement.

Comment: Use something like `ng-model="selectedRooms"`, and `ng-options="room.name for room in allRooms"`. And there you go: selectedRooms is the array of selected rooms.

Comment: I already have an array of selectedRooms. The problem is I want to display the actual Room objects, based on a filter on ID of the object. I want to only show the objects that have an ID present in my selected array.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What is `selectedRooms`? Its name implies that it's an array, containing rooms, and that it only contains the selected rooms. So, you already have your array or Room objects that are selected, don't you. If not, what is selectedRooms?

Comment: Check the edit. I included more examples and code. It should clear things up. selectedRooms is nothing. selectedReport is a complex object. selectedReport.rooms is an array of Room objects.

Comment: So, selectedReport.rooms is the array of all rooms, displayed in the select box. And you want to select some of them using the select box, and have the selected rooms stored in some variable, right? So, you need something like `<select ng-model="selectedRooms" ng-options="room.name for room in selectedReport.rooms" multiple></select>`. That's all you need. Test it. Read the documentation of ngOptions.

Comment: .... Read the question closer please. I already have a model bound correctly. Vars[var.name] is a scope variable properly binding to the select. I'm trying to do something seperate of that utilizing the data inside of this scope variable.

Comment: As it sets, Vars[var.name] is only an array of Ids as that is what my remote API expects. I want to filter ALL rooms (selectedReport.rooms) by ID using the data in my bound scope variable Vars[var.name].

Comment: It's not bound correctly, since you have an array of IDs, and you would like an array of Rooms instead. It's much simpler to display rooms when you have an array of rooms. And it's simpler to get an array of IDs from an array of rooms than an array of rooms from an array of IDs. So, bind the select to an array of rooms, and when sending a request to the backend, transform the array of rooms to an array of IDs.

Comment: I'm aware of how to do that. I was just hoping I could utilize a filter in such a way. Hence the question about filters, not restructuring my logic, code, or model. The model being used is very intentional and changing that would dramatically alter the functionality of several other things.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a custom filter to achieve what i needed.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name lodgicalWebApp.directive:lodReportVariableCgflookup
 * @description
 * # lodReportVariableCgflookup
 */
angular.module('lodgicalWebApp')
  .directive('lodReportVariableRoomFilter', [ function ( Report, Rooms) {


    return {
      template: ' \
      <div class="form-group" ng-show="selectedReport.rooms.length > 0"> \
        <label for="{{var.name}}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{var.name}}</label> \
        <div class="col-sm-5"> \
          <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="Vars[var.name]"  class="form-control"> \
            <option ng-repeat="room in selectedReport.rooms track by room.id" value="{{room.id}}" >{{room.name}}</option> \
          </select> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
      <div class="form-group" ng-show="selectedReport.rooms.length == 0"> \
        <label class="col-sm-8 control-label">Loading Rooms...</label> \
      </div> \
      <div class="form-group" ng-show="Vars[var.name].length >0"> \
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Selected Rooms: </label> \
        <div class="col-sm-5"> \
          <ul> \
             <li ng-repeat = "selectedRoom in selectedReport.rooms | selectedRooms: Vars[var.name] "> \
                {{ selectedRoom.name  }} \
             </li> \
          </ul> \
        </div> \
      </div> \
  ',
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attr){
        scope.Vars[scope.var.name] = [""] ;

      }
    };

  }]);
```

Filter:

```
angular.module('lodgicalWebApp').filter('selectedRooms', function() {
    return function(rooms, ids) {
        var filtered=[];
        angular.forEach(rooms, function(v,k){
            if(ids.indexOf(v.id) > -1){
                filtered.push(v);
            }
        });

        return filtered;

    }
});
```